# Getting the name of the latest artifact in a raw nexus repository

Tags: curl, nexus

I'm trying to use Nexus api for Nexus PRO 3.38.1-01.
What I want to do is to get the name of the latest uploaded asset in a repository named management in the folder /rpms/test. What I tried to do is to use the following curl:

```
curl -L -X GET "nexus-url/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository=management&group=/rpms/test" -H "accept: application/json" --output file
```

However it downloads the file rather than giving me some metadata about the file like its name. Is it possible to do using Nexus api?

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip download form path and specify group with dots instead of slashes. Try like this:

```
curl -L -X GET "nexus-url/service/rest/v1/search/assets/?sort=version&repository=management&group=rpms.test"
```

You can get more details on the API page:
[Nexus 3 Search API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/integrations/rest-and-integration-api/search-api)